# check for previous records for specific value

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need help in teradata where I need to check if the current STS_CD = '3' then look through the previous records and check if STS_IN has 'Y' for that EMP_ID and get corresponding UPDT_DT value.
I need to populate the value for all the records just not for the current record.

Can you please help how to achieve this ?

`EMP_ID  STS_IN  STS_CD  UPDT_DT   NEW_COLUMN
123       N       3     2/5/2020    2/3/2020
123       N       4     2/4/2020    2/3/2020
123       Y       5     2/3/2020    2/3/2020
123       N       6     2/2/2020`

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You're saying where sts_in = '3', but it has Y and N.  Even assuming you meant STS_CD, it's not clear how you want to derive your new date.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the current record STS_CD = '3' then I have to look if any of the previous record has STS_IN = 'Y' then get corresponding UPDT_DT value, in this case 3rd row has STS_IN = 'Y' and UPDT_DT '2/3/2020' and populate this value in the current record.

Comment: Can there be more than one row with STS_IN=Y for a given EMP_ID? If so, please clarify how that should be handled.

Comment: Hi Fred, Yes, there can be more than 1 row with STS_IN = Y then take the most recent record from the previous rows

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give the results you are looking for

```
SELECT EMP_ID, STS_IN, STS_CD, UPDT_DT,
  LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN STS_IN = 'Y' THEN UPDT_DT END IGNORE NULLS)
    OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY UPDT_DT ASC) as NEW_COLUMN
FROM EMP
ORDER BY EMP_ID, UPDT_DT DESC
```